# how to schedule recurring Teams channel meetings in Teams Calendar by Using API

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create a scheduled meeting in the teams channel by using API, I haven't found any API for that, Please provide me that API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through [event resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) to Create an event in the user's default calendar or specified calendar. You can use recurrence property to set the recurrence pattern for the event.

**Update :**
Currently API to create event in team channel is not available.

Comment: I have gone through the document its not working , Please provide us the direct API to create event in teams channel

Comment: I have edited my answer, Currently API to create event in team channel is not available.

Comment: So is there any road map to get this available

Comment: @lakshminarayana - We do not have any plan recently.
You can raise a user voice here: 
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new